# Add line information in Notification Template

Tags: acumatica

I saw in the help files that the line information can be added to the notification template.

From Help

> You can include information from document detail lines in
>   notifications by adding a foreach loop to the body of the notification
>   template in the **HTML** format. For instance, you can use the following
>   construction for notifications on opportunities:

```
<foreach view="Products”> 
    ((Products.InventoryID)) - ((Products.Quantity)) - ((Products.CuryExtPrice)) <br> 
</foreach>
```

I tried to put similar body in HTML, but when i save, it disappears!!!
I tried in version 5.3 and Acumatica 2017 R2
The following is what i tried to add for purchase requisition line information.

```
<foreach view="Lines”> 
    ((Lines.InventoryID)) - ((Lines.OrderQty)) - ((Lines.CuryEstUnitCost))  
</foreach>
```

In the Acumatica 2017 R2, I am getting an error saying

> There is no active notification source to process the operation

Answer (score 1):

Issue what you are seeing is due to incorrect closing quote.

[image]

`"Products”` should be `"Products"` and

`"Lines”` should be `"Lines"`

Also, there's no need to switch to HTML format.